# nusoap doesn't work : XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 1: Not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

When I try to use a function with nusoap_client, I obtain this error :

> XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 1: Not well-formed (invalid token)

There is my code :

```
<?php 
require_once('./lib/nusoap.php');

$client = new nusoap_client("./include/Authentication.xml","wsld");
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
}

$param = array('login' => '***','password'=>'***');
$result = $client->call('startSession', array('parameters' => $param));
// Check for a fault
if ($client->fault) {
    echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    // Check for errors
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        // Display the error
        echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    } else {
        // Display the result
        echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
echo '<h2>Request</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
```

I don't know where it came from

If someone have the answer thanks in advance

Comment: We need to see your code otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Ok thanks to answer me, I edit my post